# Spring data redis storing maps that has complex data as values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I'm trying to store objects of the following class in redis using spring data.

```java
public abstract class MyClass implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private Int count;
    private Map<String, Object> data;
}
```

The Object stored in the Map can be anything from String to Map and List and it's not possible to say what it's going to be beforehand. I'm having a hard time making this work because Redis keeps throwing errors when trying to serialize and deserialize data.

So, later I decided to convert data of any type to String before passing it to Redis for storing. However, I still has a use case where I want to store a Map with List of Strings as values. This works fine with the new approach when storing data. But when I try to read it, it's what is returned from the list is a single byte value inside the list, not the strings.

This is my redis configuration.

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration standaloneConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(
                HOST_NAME,
                PORT
        );
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(standaloneConfig);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        template.afterPropertiesSet();
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    RedisCustomConversions redisCustomConversions(
            MapToBytesConverter m2bConverter, BytesToMapConverter b2mConverter
    ) {
        return new RedisCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
                m2bConverter,
                b2mConverter
        ));
    }
```

These are the two converter classes.

```java
@Component
@ReadingConverter
public class BytesToMapConverter implements Converter<byte[], Map<String, Object>> {

    private final RedisSerializer<Object> serializer;

    public BytesToMapConverter() {
        serializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> convert(byte[] source) {
        return (Map<String, Object>) serializer.deserialize(source);
    }
}


@Component
@WritingConverter
public class MapToBytesConverter implements Converter<Map<String, Object>, byte[]> {

    private final RedisSerializer<Object> serializer;

    public MapToBytesConverter() {
        serializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] convert(Map<String, Object> source) {
        return serializer.serialize(source);
    }
}
```

The repository is simply a crudrepository.

```java
@Repository
public interface MyClassRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, String>{

}
```

Can you help me figure out what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.